# Sorting array issue

Tags: php, pdo, rss

i combined 2 queries: `$stmt1` and `$stmt2` into a third array (`$results`) to merge all results and use them to output 1 rss feed... the feeds works but it's listing all results from `$stmt1` by `event_start` first and then, results from `$stmt2` by `event_start`... i want to sort by both 'combined' results `event_start`

```
<?
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

$rssfeed = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>";
$rssfeed .= "<rss version='2.0'>";
$rssfeed .= "<channel>";
$rssfeed .= "<title></title>";
$rssfeed .= "<link></link>";
$rssfeed .= "<description></description>";
$rssfeed .= "<language>en-us</language>";

$db1 = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host1.';dbname='.$db_name1,$db_username1,$db_pass1);
$db2 = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host2.';dbname='.$db_name2,$db_username2,$db_pass2);

$db1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$stmt1 = $db1->query("SELECT event_start, title, s_description FROM special_events WHERE event_start >= NOW() ORDER BY event_start ASC");
$stmt2 = $db2->query("SELECT event_start, title, s_description FROM special_events WHERE event_start >= NOW() ORDER BY event_start ASC");

$results = array_merge($stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$events = array();
foreach ($results as $key => $row) {    

$rssfeed .= "<item>";
$date[$key] = $row['event_start'];
$rssfeed .= "<title>".htmlentities($row['title'])."</title>";
$rssfeed .= "<description>".htmlentities($row['s_description'])."</description>";
$rssfeed .= "<link>http://link.com</link>";
$rssfeed .= "<pubdate>".$row['event_start']."</pubdate>";
$rssfeed .= "</item>";  
}
$rssfeed .= '</channel>';
$rssfeed .= '</rss>';

array_multisort($date, SORT_ASC, $results); //not working

echo ($rssfeed);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) your `$results` array before the `foreach` call:

```
usort($results, function($row_a, $row_b) {
    if ($row_a['event_start'] > $row_b['event_start']) {
        return 1;
    } else if ($row_a['event_start'] < $row_b['event_start']) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Note that this code does a very basic comparison, which would work only for strings or numbers. If `$row_a` and `$row_b` are date strings, you'll need to cast them as DateTime. I hope you get the idea.